# Getting Strings from HTML with JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need help in getting strings from HTML with JSOUP.

The document is built like:

```
<body>
   <span class="a-touch">
      <div class"a-container">
         <div class"a-box">
            <div class="a-row a-spacing-small">
              <b>string1</b><br/>string2 97<br/>String3
              <br/>string4</>string5<br/>
          </div>
```

Now i need to get the strings.
I googled but only was able to found examples for tables and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code gets you the `strings` array which contains the text content of the `a-row` div, split by line breaks:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
Elements a_row_div = doc.select(".a-row");
String[] strings = Jsoup.clean(a_row_div.html(), "", Whitelist.none(), 
    new OutputSettings().prettyPrint(false)).split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings are all stored in `TextNode`s in JSoup.

Use `(Node n : Element.childNodes()` collection to iterate over all the nodes. The only nodes that are usually relevant are of type Element or TextNode. Use `if (n instanceof TextNode)` to test for and operate on all innerText, and `if (n instanceof Element)` to make a recursive call on all sub-elements.

Comment: The problem i have here is that there are also some other "div-branches" in this, where is also some text in.
The code i showed above is only the branch i need.
But it's nice to know, i can use it for another problem now!